# templates in c# using generic type error

Tags: c#, templates, generics

I'm working on a project on c#.
I'm using templates for class name State, here's the code:

```
class State<T>
{
   private T state; //so T could be string or Cell
}
```

and I want to initialize it with a class named Cell

```
public class Cell 
{
  int currentRow,currentColumn;
  Char value;

  public Cell()
  {
    this.currentRow = 4;
    this.currentColumn = 7;
    this.value='0';
  } 
}
```

Now I want a new `State<Cell>` to be my initial State, saying:

```
public class Maze
{
  public State<Cell> initialState;        
  public void CreateMaze(string name, int type)  //creating maze
  {     
    Board Maze = new Cell[size, size]; //board is matrix of cells
    currentRow = random.Next(0, size);
    currentCol = random.Next(0, size);
    Maze[currentRow, currentCol].value = '*';
    initialState = State<Maze[currentRow, currentCol]>; 
  }
}
```

gives me error "using the generic type requires one argument"
help..?

Comment: Generics are parametrized by types (i.e. classes or value types), not by objects (i.e. instances of classes) and values.

Comment: you're trying to use an object instance as a type parameter, like @TerraPass said.  You can't do that

Comment: so how do I do that assigning? it's still a State

Comment: Well, I'm not clear what are you trying to do, but try to replace last line with `initialState = State<Maze> (currentRow, currentCol);` and see how it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
initialState = State<Maze[currentRow, currentCol]>;
```

This will not fly, since a type parameter (`T` in `State<T>`) needs to be a class or other type, not an object or a value.

You have correctly declared the `initialState` field in your `Maze` class as `State<Cell>`. 
However, because you have declared no constructors in `State<T>`, the only thing you can do to initialize this field, outside of leaving `null` as its value, is:

```
initialState = new State<Cell>();
```

This line creates a new object of type `State<Cell>`. The type `State<Cell>` is created at runtime, based on generic `State<T>`, you've defined, using a process called "reification" (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31876747/1051764) for more info). What you get as a result is a type (a class in your case), which is, basically, `State<T>` with every occurrence of `T` in its body replaced by `Cell`.

Since the only thing you have in your `State<T>` is a single private field, this class (and its instance) is pretty useless.

To make any use of `State<T>`, you can mark its `state` field as `public`. Optionally, you can change it to a property and maybe declare a constructor:

```
class State<T>
{
    public T state {get;set;}

    public State(T state)
    {
        this.state = state;
    } 
}
```

Now you can initialize your `initialState` in `Maze` like so:

```
initialState = new State<Cell>(Maze[currentRow, currentCol]);
```

*(As a side note, do avoid naming your variables with a capital letter, since capitalized names are usually used for classes and methods in C#. Look, even StackOverflow's syntax highlighter is confused.)*

Having a public property, you can access the `Cell` instance, you stored in `initialState`, simply as `initialState.state`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing C++ with C#.

Unlike templates in C++, you cannot use instances of a type to access a generic type. You must use the *name* of the type. This means that this line needs some correcting:

```
initialState = State<Maze[currentRow, currentCol]>;
```

I can only guess what you want to do here. I guess you want to create a new `State<Cell>` object, of which the `state` property is `Maze[currentRow, currentCol]`.

Hopefully, I'm correct.

In C#, every time you need to create a new object, you need to use the `new` keyword and call the constructor of the type. So you need to do this:

```
initialState = new State<Cell>();
```

"But wait! The `state` field haven't been set yet!" you shouted. Yes, because at the moment, it can't be set as it is a private field. You can either

- turn that into a property (recommended) or;
- change it to public.

If you turn it to a property, it will look like this:

```
public T MyState {
    get; set;
}
```

You can also make it immutable, dunno whether you want to do that.

```
public T MyState {
    get;
}
```

Then, write a constructor that takes a state parameter and assign that to the property:

```
public State(T state) {
    this.MyState = state;
}
```

Now you can initialize your `State<Cell>` like this:

```
initialState = new State<Cell>(Maze[currentRow, currentCol]);
```

I think you get the idea by now, basically,

**You cannot set a property/field of a generic class simply by putting in an instance of the class in the place where a generic type parameter should go. Instead, you need to set the property/field manually by an assignment statement.**