# How to know the required interface/contract of template arguments in C++?

Tags: c++, templates

Sorry for the newbie question, but I have a feeling I am missing something here:

If I have a certain class template which looks like this (basically the only way to pass a lambda to a function in C++, unless I am mistaken):

```
template<typename V, typename F>
class Something
{
public:
     int some_method(V val, F func) {
         double intermediate = val.do_something();
         return func(intermediate);
     }
}
```

By reading the implementation of this class, I can see that the `V` class must implement `double do_something()`, and that `F` must be a function/functor with the signature `int F(double)`.

However, in languages like Java or C#, the constraints for the generic parameters are explicitly stated in the generic class signature, so they are obvious without having to look at the source code, e.g.

```
class Something<V> where V : IDoesSomething // interface with the DoSomething() method
{
     // func delegate signature is explicit
     public int SomeMethod(V val, Func<double, int> func)  
     {
         double intermediate = val.DoSomething();
         return func(intermediate);
     }
}
```

My question is: **how do I know how to implement more complex input arguments in practice?** Can this somehow be documented using code only, when writing a library with template classes in C++, or is the only way to parse the code manually and look for parameter usage?

(or third possibility, add methods to the class until the compiler stops failing)

Comment: From C++20 you can use [concepts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints), which seems like what you're looking for.

Comment: @cigien: sorry, fixed. Weird, so I am not mistaken then. It took a while for this to be added to the standard. :) But how do you deduce these signatures in practice?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Most of the machinery for template argument deduction has been in the language for a long time. Are you asking how compilers implement this? Either way, you should edit the question accordingly.

Comment: @cigien: no, I am not asking about how the compiler deduces the arguments, what I am asking is, how does a programmer know how to implement a concrete instance of `T` which can be passed to `template <class T>`? For example, for `template <typename T> T max(T a, T b) { return a > b ? a : b; }`, your `T` class must implement the `>` operator. You learn this from reading the entire function. So, a large templated class might contain dozens of these constraints, and coming from C# I expected that it would be easier to deduce them (for a programmer).

Comment: In other words, if you have a function `int doSomething(BaseClass b)`, and `BaseClass` is an abstract class, you only need to look at the `BaseClass` to know which methods you need to implement. You don't need to look at the body of the `doSomething` function to see this.

Comment: That's what Concepts gives you: you could say something like `template<Comparable T> T max(T, T);` and not have to look at the definition. Again, please add all these clarifications into the question, not as comments.

Comment: If all you are doing is trying to get a lambda into a function, you can instead "wrap" the lambda with a `std::function`, and pass that.  If the functions you're trying to pass as parameters always have the same signature, this avoids having to use template nonsense to make it work.  [Example of std::function](https://shaharmike.com/cpp/lambdas-and-functions/#simple-example).

Answer (score 3):

C# and Java Generics have similar syntax and some common uses with C++ templates, but they are very different beasts.

[Here is a good overview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31876747/1774667).

In C++, by default template checking was done by instantiation of code, and requrements are in documentation.

Note that much of the requirements of C++ templates is semantic not syntactic; iterators need not only have the proper operations, those operations need to have the proper meaning.

You can check syntactic properties of types in C++ templates.  Off the top of my head, there are 6 basic ways.

1. You can have a traits class requirement, like `std::iterator_traits`.
2. You can do SFINAE, an accidentally Turing-complete template metaprogramming technique.
3. You can use concepts and/or requires clauses if your compiler is modern enough.
4. You can generate `static_assert`s to check properties
5. You can use traits ADL functions, like `begin`.
6. You can just duck type, and use it as if it had the properties you want.  If it quacks like a duck, it is a duck.

All of these have pluses and minuses.

The downside to *all* of them is that they can be harder to set up than "this parameter must inherit from the type Foo".  Concepts can handle that, only a bit more verbose than Java.

---

Java style type erasure can be dominated using C++ templates.  `std::function` is an example of a duck typed type eraser that allows unrelated types to be stored as values; doing something as restricted as Java is rarely worthwhile, as the machinery to do it is harder than making something more powerful.

C# reification cannot be fully duplicated by C++, because C#'s runtime environment ships with a compiler, and can effectively compile a new type when you instantiate at runtime.  I have seen people ship compilers with C++ programs, compile dynamic libraries, then load and execute them, but that isn't something I'd advise.

---

Using modern [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20), you can:

```
template<Number N>
struct Polynomial;
```

where `Number` is a **concept** which checks `N` (a type) against its properties.  This is a bit like the Java signature stuff on steroids.

And by [c++23](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b23) you'll be able to use compile time reflection to do things that make templates look like preprocessor macros.